# Using Terminal (OSX) to remove "?" character at end of basename

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a list of files with an unknown character at the end (shown as a "?")

My goal is to

- remove the unknown character in the basenames shown as ? for every file in the folder

Here is the directory/folder path where the files are located:

/Users/MyName/Documents/InfoNotParsed

Here are the names of the files in the folder:

```
TextInformation?.txt
TextInformation2?.txt
TextInformation3?.txt
```

Here are the commands I am attempting to run in the terminal in order to remove the "?" at the end of the base name before the extension:

```
cd /Users/MyName/Documents/InfoNotParsed

for f in *; do mv — “$f” “$f//\?/}”; done
```

I am stuck at the command line saying:

```
for dquote>
```

Here is the entire Terminal text in the shell:

```
MyName@Name-MBP ~ % cd /Users/MyName/Documents/InfoNotParsed 
MyName@Name-MBP InfoNotParsed % for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "${f//\?/}; done
for dquote>
```

Any advice?

Comment: You want quotes (specifically `"`) _around_ `${f//\?/}`. _Around_ means before **and after**.

Comment: Alright I'll try that!

Comment: It ran, but didn't remove the ? at the end of the basename; here's the output after I added the double quote: usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to match an *unknown* character using a `?`, but the `?` is not there it’s just the terminal displaying an unknown using one.

Try listing what you wish to keep and using `tr` to remove the complement, something like:

```
for f in *.txt; do g=`echo -n "$f" | tr -C -d "\40-\177"`; mv -- "$f" "$g"; done
```

That is far from foolproof but may work for your particular situation.